# Yii: Update model values before actionCreate and actionUpdate

Tags: post, controller, yii, action

I have a Location model with the following attributes -

```
id
City
State
Country
```

I wan't the user to be able to select from a list of existing states / countries, and if an additional item needs to be added it may be typed into a textbox. I've modified the `_form.php` partial as follows -

```
// city
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'city',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100)); ?>

// state
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'state', CHtml::listData(Location::model()->findAll(), 'state', 'state')); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::textField('state2','',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100)); ?>

// country
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'country', CHtml::listData(Location::model()->findAll(), 'country', 'country')); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::textField('country2','',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100)); ?>
```

`state2` and `country2` are not a part of the model attributes. Now, in the Location Controller I have the following action -

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Location;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Location']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Location'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

I want to set the values like this before this action executes -

```
if(!empty($_POST['state2'])) $model->state = $_POST['state2'];
if(!empty($_POST['country2'])) $model->country = $_POST['country2'];
```

**What I've tried so far**

**1. Attempt 1**
I added the lines directly to both `actionCreate` and `actionUpdate`. However, I don't think this is a clean solution.

**1. Attempt 2**
I tried adding a filter like this -

```
public function filterAlternateData($filterChain)
{
  if(!empty($_POST['state2'])) $_POST['Location[state]'] = $_POST['state2'];
  if(!empty($_POST['country2'])) $_POST['Location[country]'] = $_POST['country2'];
  $filterChain->run();
}
```

Then I modified the filters() function like this so that it's bound to the create and update actions -

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        'alternateData + create, update',
    );
}
```

But this did not work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume this is happening in a CRUD operation based upon the actionCreate() method.

Personally I would create a separate form for the create functionality with the following attributes.

Form

- Cities
- States
- Countries
- New city (not required)
- New State (not required)
- New Country (not required)

Then in the form validation you can check to see if the user has entered a city, state or country which already exists etc.

Comment: Seems like the right option for me  here. I was restricting myself to the factory CRUD scaffold.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the lines in beforeSave() method (you will have to override it) of your model.

Comment: isn't `beforeValidate()` called before `beforeSave()`? Won't validation will fail if drop down list is empty (first record insertion)?

Comment: it depends on the validations you have set in your model... if you have set a 'required' validation for the fields, the validations will fail. But in your case, they can be empty and not set, so no the validation should not fail.